# Angular: How can I override a property Input of type Function

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using a 3rd party library that defines one of its component inputs as such

```
fetchChildren: (node: object) => Observable<object[]>;
```

So in my implementation I define and call it like this:

```
<my-component [fetchChildren]="fetchChildren"></my-component>

public fetchChildren(node: any): Observable<any[]> {
  return of(node.items);
}
```

The issue I am having is that I need to pass an additional paraeter to the `fetchChildren` method but it seems like I am unable to modify the method signature.  I have tried adding a parameter to the calling Component but I am unable to access any parameters

```
myAdditionalProp: number = 1;

public fetchChildren(node: any): Observable<any[]> {
  console.log(this.myAdditionalProp); //undefined
  return of(node.items);
}
```

It turns out that calling `this` inside the function returns an instance of the `my-component` object, not my main class component.

So I need to figure out how to either be able to pass an additional parameter to `fetchChildren` or be able to access my calling components attributes.

Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sligtly change the method signature

```
public fetchChildren = (node: any) => {
 ...
```

this way you would have a bound function created for this wrapper component and you would be able to access "this.myAdditionalProp" without any issues